# UITextField in Prototype Cells

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextfield

I am trying to create a prototype table using TableViewController with a text field in each cell. Here is my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITextField *teamNumber = nil;
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        teamNumber = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(45, 30, 200, 40)];
        teamNumber.tag = 100;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:teamNumber];
    }
    else {
        teamNumber = [cell.contentView viewWithTag:100];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

When I run the simulator, there are no text fields. However, when I replace UITextField with UISwitch (and replace CGRectMake with CGRectZero), I see a switch in each cell. Can anyone advise?

Thanks,

Jordan

Comment: textfield should be there try to set some text to textfield. Or set some property to textfield, like set style, etc.

Comment: check textField frame set it to  x= 0 y = 0. It should be there but probably goes out of the cell frame.

Comment: Thanks. The text field is not visible, but after setting x and y to 0, if I tap the top left of the cell, it allows me to type text. Any ideas on how to make it visible?

Comment: Solution - I just had to set the border style. Thanks for your help